# publish wordpress comments as post in a specific category

Tags: wordpress

for a little votingtool i'm looking for a solution.
the visitor can give a comment on a page. if the editor approves the comment, it should automatically published as a post in a specific category. any ideas how to solve this problem, any startingpoint for me? a plugin?

Answer (score 1):

G'Day efendi, a possible plugin as a starter is SEO Super Comments.  This plugin converts all comments to their own dynamic page.  At the very least it should give you some coding ideas.

Comment: i found a plugin named "User Submitted Posts". i think, that solves my problem. thank you.